# Using Web Portal for SSO

Tags: authentication, reverse-proxy, authorization

I have several (.Net) web apps that are currently hosted on our intranet. I want to expose them to (authorized) external users. I want a web portal that I can use for the authorization with little or no modification to the web apps.  (I.e. I would like a portal that acts like a reverse proxy and only allows authorized users to access the application.)

Are there any products that do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: We are expecting to have 1,000 - 10,000 external users. Ideally, we would like to have an automated process for creating ID's and self service for password resets, account information updates, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're running .Net I assume Windows and IIS, and likely a domain for user authentication.  Is there anything stopping you from turning on the directory security in IIS to secure the folders where the applications live?  The users can then use their domain credentials to login when prompted.  The browser and IIS would handle the authentication before your web app could be viewed.

Comment: That is a good idea but I forgot to mention that we are expecting to have 1,000 - 10,000 external users. Ideally, we would like to have an automated process for creating ID's and self service for password resets, account information updates, etc.

Comment: That makes it more complex, but it's still possible to automate the accounts by using tools to update Active Directory.  See this article for an introduction: http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/27378/access-denied-automating-user-account-creation-in-ad.html, then see this Microsoft KB article for details: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=237677